Mini-split options and its suitability?
I recently bought a new home with no central AC, except for one in-the-wall unit in a bedroom. The house spans 2,000 sqft across three floors and is heated with hot water baseboards from an oil furnace about 5-7 years old.
Considering my options, I'm leaning towards a ductless mini-split system to efficiently cool and potentially heat the house. I'm in the Northeast where winters are cold, so having a dual-purpose system seems practical. Would a Cooper and Hunter ductless mini-split system be a good choice for my needs, providing both cooling and supplemental heating? My main concern is energy efficiency compared to running multiple wall AC units simultaneously.
An HVAC contractor recommended a system with 6 indoor units and 2 multi-zone compressors, all under a 7-year warranty from Cooper and Hunter. However, I'm unfamiliar with them in this context and unsure about their reliability. Should I consider quotes from HVAC companies specializing in Fujitsu or Mitsubishi systems instead? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
I'm going back and forth between the pricing for a ceiling cassette vs wall mount, and see there are other options too, if anyone has experience with ceiling cassettes vs wall mounts or maybe just a better brand to go with id really appreciate it, im currently debating this unit
https://southminisplits.com/collections/3-zone/products/3-zone-cooper-hunter-36-000-btu-3-zone-9k-9k-18k-ceiling-cassettes-with-installation-kits-23-9-seer2-4-ton-tri-zone-ductless-multi-mini-split-air-conditioner?variant=41535622479987
and then this unit too (aesthetically speaking i dont care too much about the look of the wall mount vs ceiling cassette, but if the cassette is more efficient i'd defnitely prefer that over the wall mount)
https://southminisplits.com/collections/3-zone/products/3-zone-ch-olivia-2x9kand18k?variant=41423132983411

Product recommendation are off topic.  Without knowing how the rooms are laid out, plus windows the sun beats in, plus if the doors to the rooms are closed or open, plus insulation level, you really need eyes on the problem/solution.  I am just north of the northeast and I might have 20 hours on a small window AC unit in the last twenty years.

I have had very good results with Senville units. The company has excellent customer support as well.   (Yeah, I know product recommendation is off topic.)

@Traveler, Mini splits do not have air handlers to go into an attic.  Many locals have taken up codes to disallow attic air handlers as well.

do not forget the power requirements for each unit. Mostly the standard 120 volt 15 amp is not enough

The wall units are powered from the compressor stand outside.  The power to the compressor is usually 240v 30 or 40 A depending on the size.  Some single units are as low as 120v 20A

From what I recall when I was shopping, the wall mount is the most efficient head option, because the fan has almost no restriction. My compressor units that power the inside units are 240V 15A. With decent insulation I turn them to AC for an hour once a month in summer just to keep the moving parts from stagnating all summer. They are mostly heat.

OP here - highest it gets is about 95-105 degrees, sun is generally only beating in thru windows on bedroom/living room side, got one quote and it was 12k for system + installation mitsubishi - debating on whether or not mini split would be best since it gets pretty cold here in winter (down to about -5 very bad winters down to -19 or so but only for a couple days), sound is not issue and plan on doing 230v
